# [ASPX][JavaScript][DevExpress] Infinite location.reload() loop after callback

Tags: javascript, devexpress, aspxgridview

I've been having a problem with refreshing the page with a callback. The event is made in javascript; It adds a little table that shows the month and year and refreshes after showing it but at the time of refreshing, the refresh enters into an infinite loop that refreshes at first the page loads.

the code of the event is the following one:

```
script type="text/javascript">
    function gvProducts_Callback(s, e) {
        var table = document.getElementById("Content_gv_table");
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
        var newRow = "<tr> <th> [... the table field name goes here ...] </th> </tr>";
        rows.innerHTML = newRow + rows.innerHTML;
location.reload();
```

}

and the event call back is set after the dev express gridview.

```
              </Columns>
                    <SettingsSearchPanel />
                    <SettingsPager PageSize="250" />
                    <ClientSideEvents Init="gvProducts_Callback"/>
```

PS: I have tried using an if with a boolean variable that turned true after the row was created but turned the same in the end.

Have a great day and thanks in advance

Comment: Your function doesn't have a closing bracket. Are you storing somewhere newely inserted row?

Comment: sorry for not adding the closet bracket, no, what it does is creating the row everytime in loads the page.

Comment: Does this initialize on page reload? Init="gvProducts_Callback"

Comment: it supposed to initialize after you save changes on the dev express grid view